# first-child selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to build a simple box system and I need to remove the right margin of the first child.

I have tried both **first-child** and **first-of-type** and still cannot properly target the intended class.

I have read through a number of different examples and still cannot find a solution.

**Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewgood/Lvd44upd/1/) and help me remove the margin-left from the first child.**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:white;
}
.box.full {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.box.half {
  width: 49%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.half:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I now have a better understanding of how to use the first-child selector. To solve my problem, I simply introduced a .row class so that first-child actually targets the proper element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `.half` class element is not the first child of `.container`. It is the second child, thus your selector does not work.

I would suggest using

```
.box.full + .box.half {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

to specify that any `.box.half` coming immediately after a `.box.full` have the margin you desire.

Comment: Exaclty. Via w3schools: "The :first-child selector matches every element that is the **first child of its parent**".

Answer (score 1):

You are targetting the second child indeed :

```
.box.half:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Try this instead :)

```
.box.half {
  width: 49%;
}

.box.half + .box.half
{
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

`.box.half` ONLY if preceeded by `.box.half` will have `margin-left: 2%`.

No more left margin, no more right margin, 49 + 49 + 2 = 100 , profit.

See your Fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvd44upd/3/

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
.box.half { width: 49%; }
```

and

```
.box.half:last-child { margin-left: 1%; }
```

. Seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvd44upd/2/).

Answer (score 0):

It because the first half box is not the first child of its parent, it is the second. So quick solution is .box.half:nth-child(2).